# log1pexp is not available in Tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, math, floating-point, numeric, tensorflow2.0

`log1pexp(x)` implements `log(1 + exp(x))` in a numerically stable way. Unfortunately this function does not exist within `tensorflow.math` module.

This is actually quite simple to implement, using `log1p` which is available in tensorflow. The following is based on https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsFuns.jl/blob/0beb42294785787ac58fec247cd5d225a99e6d0f/src/basicfuns.jl#L67.

```
def log1pexp(x):
    if x < 9:
        return log1p(exp(x))
    elif x < 16:
        return x + exp(-x)
    else:
        return x
```

I can define this function but I fear it might be slower than a native TF implementation? Also I would like this to just work if `x` is a tensor (it should apply element-wise), but I'm not sure how to deal with the branch.

Any suggestions?

If I have to implement it by hand, I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to make it fast as possible (without having to write it in C).

Answer (score 1):

Try [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where?version=stable):

```
x = tf.range(20,dtype=tf.float64)
# [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
result = tf.where(tf.less(x,9),
                  tf.log1p(tf.exp(x)),
                  tf.where(tf.less(x,16),
                           x + tf.exp(-x),
                           x))

# [ 0.69314718  1.31326169  2.12692801  3.04858735  4.01814993  5.00671535
#   6.00247569  7.00091147  8.00033541  9.00012341 10.0000454  11.0000167
#  12.00000614 13.00000226 14.00000083 15.00000031 16.         17.
#  18.         19.        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that tensorflow does have a native implementation of this function, but under the name `tensorflow.math.softplus`.